# How to get the current date in PHP, and add 1 month to the current date?

Tags: php, date

I'm coding a script where I require to save the current date, and the date 1 month from that date. I am pretty sure that the `time()` variable works, but I am not sure how to `+1 month` onto that?

Any ideas, suggestions. Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($today)));
```

or use [DateTime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

```
$dt1 = new DateTime();
$today = $dt1->format('Y-m-d');

$dt2 = new DateTime('+1 month');
$date = $dt2->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I think you missed strtotime($today), I think the correct way is to be like that `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));`

Answer (score 5):

```
$time = strtotime("2010-12-11");
$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));
```

(OR)

```
strtotime( "+1 month", strtotime( $time ) );
```

this returns a timestamp that can be used with the date function

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

**Current Date:**

```
echo "Today is " . date("Y/m/d");
```

**1 Month to the Current Date:**

```
$time = strtotime(date("Y/m/d"));
$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$current_time = date("Y-M-d h:i:s",time()); // Getting Current Date & Time
print $current_time; // Current Date & Time Printing for display purpose
$future_timestamp = strtotime("+1 month");  // Getting timestamp of 1 month from now
$final_future = date("Y-M-d h:i:s",+$future_timestamp); //  Getting Future Date & Time of 1 month from now
print $final_future; // Printing Future time for display purpose




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

shorter : $today=date("Y-m-d"); $date=

Comment: you might have missed what follows `$date=`

Answer (score 1):

This one liner worked for me:

```
$monthFromToday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime(date("Y/m/d"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

The given answers may not give you the results you might expect or desire.

Consider:

```
$today = "29Jan2018";
$nextMonth = date('dMY', strtotime('+1 month', (strtotime($today))));
echo $today // yields 29Jan2018
echo $nextMonth // yields 01Mar2018
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current date in PHP and add 1 month to it, you can use the date and strtotime() functions. Here's how you can do it

```
// Get the current date
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

// Add 1 month to the current date
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate . ' +1 month'));

// Display the current date and the date with 1 month added
echo 'Current Date: ' . $currentDate . '<br>';
echo 'Date with 1 Month Added: ' . $newDate;
```

This code will give you the current date and the date one month from now.

*It's worth noting that the date() function and most other date-related functions in PHP typically depend on the server's system time or the time zone settings configured on the server. The date and time values returned by these functions are derived from the server's clock.*

Answer (score -1):

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$enddate = date('Y-m-01',strtotime($today. ' + 1 months'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also consider using the Carbon package.

The solution would look like this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon

$now = Carbon::now;
$now->addMonth();
```

Here is the link for reference https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28944751)

Comment: @Nick You are totally right, I've made the necessary changes.